# iOS AudioKit using `AKKeyboardView`

Tags: ios, audiokit, coremidi

The question is very simple. Is it possible to programmatically send a note on/off so it will show on the keyboard view? What I'm trying to do is link the `AKMIDICallbackInstrument` to the keyboard.

There was [an article](https://audiokitpro.com/get-the-most-out-of-your-aksequencer/) about doing something similar but it doesn't seem to be possible. (Thinking about it, the keyboard delegate should be the one handling keyboard view touch events, not the other way around...) Also checked the `AKKeyboardView` code, but it seems like there are only touch related code.

If there is no such method, are there plans to add them?

Comment: I'm the author of the article, and you are correct.  When I wrote it, I had recently implemented an animated keyboard with AKMIDICallbackInstrument, but I realize now that I used https://github.com/crashingbooth/PianoKeyboard not AKKeyboardView, which does not have this feature.  It is definitely worth adding to AKKeyboardView and I will try to add it this week.

Comment: @c_booth Thank you for the comment! Greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @c_booth Totally unrelated to the question but do you happen to know if there are iOS UI libraries that render music XML? I did some serious searching but couldn't find any. I only found one project that was just beginning.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two methods have been added to `AKKeyboardView` on the develop branch of AudioKit:

```
programmaticNoteOn(_ note: MIDINoteNumber)
programmaticNoteOff(_ note: MIDINoteNumber)
```

These allow you to programmatically simulate key presses and key releases without calling the delegate.